# Export excel with map embedded

Tags: excel, esri-maps-office

In arcgis office you have a functionality to add a map to an excel.

Now, i want to give an option to export an excel from my application(javascript, .net, or anything else) to allow the user to download an excel with the map already embedded.

It is possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first, very simple approach could be to write an HTML document containing a table with the required information and set the extension to *xls* (instead of html).
You can include the HTML image tag too and specify an URL to the picture (or map saved as a picture):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Vienna</td>
        <td>8500000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Berlin</td>
        <td>80000000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><img src="URL_To_Picture.jpg"</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML table with image opened in Excel]

Comment: This was somethin i needed sometime ago, but i think it's good :)